# If statement based on multiple columns

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets, how can I write an if statement that based on multiple columns, I can get a numerical value?

I have something like below that gives me a value if Yes or No,

```
=IF($G502="Yes",5,0)
```

If I want to say if $G502 and $H502 and $I502 and $k502 are all no, give me the value of 5?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/447561/how-to-use-the-and-and-or-functions-in-google-sheets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IF((G502="no")*(H502="no")*(I502="no")*(k502="no"), 5, 0)
```

Comment: I didn't know that ! Great answer.